# Pass Plain Text File via XMLHttpRequest fail

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I am trying to send a user uploaded text file via an XMLHttpRequest with the following code:

HTML

```
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
```

Javascript

```
function Upload_Text()
            {
                var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
                var table_type = 2; 
                if (document.myform.Table_Name_Text[0].checked == true)   {table_type = 1;}
                var Choose_Class = document.getElementById("Choose_Class").value;
                var formData = new FormData();
                var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        alert(result);

                    }
                }
                var url = "Upload_Text.php";
                url = url + "?table_type="+table_type;
                url = url + "&Choose_Class="+Choose_Class;
                formData.append("thefile", file);
                xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
                xmlhttp.send(formData);
                }
```

However with the following PHP code, I do not receive any data from the text file server side.

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['thefile'];
$table_type=$_REQUEST["table_type"];
$Choose_Class=$_REQUEST["Choose_Class"];
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($file));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
?>
```

Any help with this would be great, thanks.

Comment: You cannot upload files using AJAX easily. (Well you can with difficultly with some browsers but I have not found a way for IE and each are different.

Comment: you better submit the form

Comment: Is it not possible to use a FormData object to wrap the plain text file?

Comment: It's totally possible and I do it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding ["tmp_name"] to the file string.  So: `$file = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];`

This will get the file's temporary location.  Looking through your code everything else seems fine.

Comment: Thanks! Does exactly what I want now.